# Angular 2 Get all querystrings

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there an automated way I can get ALL of the querystrings in the address bar without knowing what the names are?

For instance I want to get all of the following:

```
reports?api=Report1&from=&to=&agentId=2&status=1&fixtureId=3&gradeId=4
```

I've had a look everywhere but I can only see examples where you can only get if it you know the name.

Comment: If you can say your requirement that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if answer should be somehow related to angular but a simple solution would be:

1. `location.search` - gets query string with all params
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string - nice package which converts queryString to params object for your convenience.

Comment: He asked about angular 2, does not angular 1

Answer (score 0):

- Import`ActivatedRoute`

  `import {  ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";`
- And initialize on constructor

  `constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   }`
- Then use this below code to getting query string

  ```
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
           let from = params['from'];                
      });
  ```

### Edit

this `this.activatedRoute.params` having all query strings . but if you want get the value then you should go with subscribe. or get the whole url and need to use `split();` the URL to get query strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in your answer you are specifically having to know that there is a query name called "from". How can I get all of them without knowing the names? :)